# What are these cute little seedlings that are growing in my houseplant soil?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, seedlings

What are these very small seedlings? They just erupted out of nowhere. Should I leave it as it is? Or should I pluck it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are cotyledons. Unless you planted the seed, you usually have to wait until the first true leaves form before ID is possible.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered without more information.

Comment: @kevinsky More information like?

Comment: A picture of the second set of leaves.  Need to wait until they are larger

Comment: @kevinsky Frankly,  I pulled them out. I had a very close look at the leaves, and I found that the leaves are more like proper leaf (Just very tiny), not like we have in cotyledons.

Comment: @kevinsky Sorry, but thought that they might disturb my recently re-potted plant(Dracaena). But I pulled a few back days back, and, hopefully, some will come, this time i will wait for them to grow large.

Comment: You have to wait. By the way, do you have a bird feeder nearby and/or use sunflower seed?

Comment: Exactly..Srihari is correct.  These seeds had to come from somewhere unless you used garden soil (big no no)!  You don't want any other plants you do not know to compete with your Dracaena.  I'd carefully repot them in tiny little pots with potting soil to see what they are.  You should be able to suss out where the extra seeds came from, yes?  Grins!

Comment: @stormy I think it was garden soil. I will wait for few days to see if the the new plants emerge or not. I think the seeds were already present in the soil, and came to life when I watered the plant.

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor The plant is kept indoor 24/7.

Comment: Then these seeds obviously came from good ole garden soil NOT TO BE USED IN POTS!!  Go get potting soil.  Give your potted plants the best environment you are able to prepare for them!!  I could go into huge detail such as you are removing a tiny chunk of a larger ecosystem possibly filled with disease that would take off when separated from the natural controls...etc.  Dump that stuff out, repot in sterilized potting soil...no rocks or gravel at the bottom of the pot and there HAS to be drainage!!  Use Osmocote 14-14-14 extended release fertilizer that only needs to be used once or twice year

Comment: @stormy My father got this soil from nursery, but I doubt it to be good for potted plants. I watered the plant 3 days back, and the soil is like muddy. The top layer hasn't dried yet. It feels like I watered it in the morning. I doubt this soil to be any good.

Comment: Very possibly!  Too much clay in the soil will hold onto the water...too long for potted plants...go ahead and repot in bagged potting soil.  I used to use the CHEAPEST bagged soil with less vermiculite and it was super.  Now they have potting soil with mycorrhizae and bacteria that come alive when watered. Costs a bit more but worth it!

Comment: @stormy I already potted two of my plants in the soil. I have posted some pics of the soil in the chat room, and I thought the soil was good soil, but turns out to be different. My Dracaena is already in shock, but I am gonna ask it as a question. Thanks Stormy :)

Comment: @stormy Changed my mind. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31826104#31826104

Comment: What do you mean, 4-K?

Comment: That soil looks like regular ole soil from the garden or from the wilderness.  Did you repot using sterilized potting soil?

Comment: @stormy I meant I won't ask the question on soil at the time of making that comment. That soil is actually a mix of Cow dung Compost with regular soil, that's what making the soil so water thirsty. :( I will post the question when I get another soil type.

Comment: Cow dung decomposed mixed with garden soil is not at all recommended to use in pots.  The soil doesn't get thirsty, it does get hydrophobic if allowed to get too dry.  Plants need the best soil and environment YOU are able to provide. The lighting, water, replacing important chemicals that don't exist in the soil and the soil is ALL our potted plants can depend upon.   A shovel full of soil removed from a larger, complex environment will not give your potted plants any kind of edge for survival.  Just sayin'.  Us humans can be so silly thinking we know best.

Comment: @stormy Any particular houseplants that would love that type of soil? Do you know Plants are more evolved than us humans?

Comment: I've tried using garden soil from time to time, even trying to sterilize it (PU).  If I were a plant of any kind being planted in artificial conditions, I would want potting soil.  'More evolved' meaning that plants have been here longer than humans?  Absolutely!  Success in evolution means being able to successfully adapt to the environment not destroying our own petrie dish. Humans have not yet found a niche where they are part of a system.  Main problem is that we've been told we are SEPARATE from all other life, so special, so entitled...our big brains are kinda useless. Love this topic!

Comment: @stormy No! I mean, any plants that would grow well in the soil I talked about(The one with cow dung in it)? Yes, they came way before us, but they are more contributive to nature. We are, on the other hand, more selfish ones. All plants and animals(except us) have learned to live and let others live. We think we are on top of everything else: the plants, animals, insects and etc.. But we are nothing without them. They are everything without us.

Comment: My goodness, 4-K we are MOST CERTAINLY on the same page!!  I know that us humans are unable to create a healthy ecosystem even within a pot. Using soil out of the garden even with lots of great chemicals (horrors to add sand, vermiculite) and sterilize.  The organisms in the larger ecosystem will not have beneficials by scooping up one shovel full of soil and although that soil drains fairly well out in the garden it won't in a pot.  Just because soil works well in the garden does not mean it is going to be helpful to any plant in a pot.  Trust me, we are on the SAME page!!

Comment: Dump that soil in your garden!  Add organic matter to your soil whatever type it is!  If it isn't decomposed completely only plant leafy plants.  Otherwise too much nitrogen for fruits, flowers.  Adding organic matter is the ONLY way to improve; sand, clay or pumice...or even silt and loam!  Not a thing else should be added except fertilizer!  I love your perspective, it is close to my own.  I am getting very tired of humans. We don't have an ecosystem of which we are a part!  What other life form is so apart from life?  We certainly won't be missed when we go extinct...Sigh.

Comment: @stormy Yes, we are on the same page. I will try to get rid of the soil, but I don't have a garden. And I agree that we are not a part of any ecosystem. We are cutting down trees and barely giving any thought to it. I just hope mother nature takes revenge on all of us humans. We think concrete is strong. Well, certainly not stronger than mother nature. If you wanna watch something related to what will happen when humans are wiped off of the face of Earth, watch this: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1173907/

Comment: It is a sad sad comment to say one is terribly embarrassed by their own species.  And to admit we could think or say our species SHOULD go extinct holds an awful lot of weight.  Animals and plants are wonderful so I kinda hang out with them and try not to do anything extreme while in town!  I am not being THAT serious...sighs.

Comment: @stormy LOL! I agree to that. I wasn't that serious either. But it's a fact: we have done more bad than good.

Comment: Not many people understand how useless we humans are.  Nice to be able to commiserate with someone else not happy with our very own species.  Thanks!

Comment: @stormy You said not to use Cow dung in potted plants at all. But this tells me something entirely different. Watch it in High quality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXBgYvhAkvU

Comment: I just watched the first minute and I am NOT happy!  All soil is good soil.  The difference is in management!  Knowledge.  Cow shit now being paraded as a cure all for soil is just bad information.  Sure it can help in certain instances, NOT POTTING SOIL.  Now listen closely; the only way to improve ANY SOIL is to add decomposed organic matter.  Pretty much just adding it to the surface is enough t attract micro and macro organisms from the soil profile up to eat (only decomposed) and then go back into the soil profile and poop it out.  They do all the mixing and aerating for free.

Comment: Unbelievable that people will make videos of stuff they have absolutely no right to be doing.  Like diets and losing weight, so much crap information.  What would you do when adding more fertilizer?  Kill your plants is what.  Using soil from the garden in pots is just wrong.  One is taking a little tiny chunk out of a huge ecosystem in order to create a smaller one and that just will not work.  I'll go watch the rest but I am telling you COW SHIT is not the wonder they are making it out to be!

Comment: @stormy I, too, don't think cow manure is good for pots. Everytime I was thinking how the owner of those pots and plants in the video was watering it. Cause I have decomposed cow dung mixed with soil and the mix is water loving. I watered it 3 weeks before, and the soil is still wet! I also saw some videos where some told to put stones or a piece of stone or a piece of broken pot on the drainage hole to help the drainage, but then I found another video saying not to put stones or pebbles in any pot. Generally, It is very difficult on Web to contrast right information from the wrong. :(

Comment: No kidding!  I learned about container planting in Master Gardener courses and when I moved to another location I had to teach the Master Gardeners about the 'perched water table' using rocks and gravel.  New location has lots of wind and they whined how do they make the pots heavier for the wind...that is not the way.  I set up demonstrations of this (upside down) perched water table.  I find just crap information all of the time out here on the internet.   Point you need to remember, if people are not successful with plants they think it is THEIR FAULT.  And go back to spend more money.

Comment: Who's "THEIR"? The plants or the people? :( @stormy

Comment: The people!  Plants are very easy to grow if one knows the basics of botany, soils, chemistry, climate both local and micro (planted in an atrium for instance), macro, micro organisms necessary in the ecosystem those plants will live.  Advertising also confuses people by promoting the idea that fertilizer is food (thus plants must be like animals), landscape fabric is for weeds, misting increases humidity and rocks at the bottom of containers (or gravel or the packing peas) helps drainage and saves money on soil and stops dirt coming out of the drain hole or that a drain hole isn't necessary.

Comment: @stormy Absolutely correct. I just re-potted my plant and after watering, I found out it to be GARDEN SOIL :O. At least people there have some idea what they are selling and buying. People here just don't give a damn about houseplants. They pot it in any kind of soil they see fit. Now I am tired cos they said it is the best soil for plants and I paid!

Comment: Hi 4-K. Since the seedlings were discarded before the plant from it grew and flowered, I don't think this can be answered. I voted to close it just so it doesn't stay in the active list of unanswered questions. I just wanted to give you a heads-up, so it doesn't look like it was personal against you!

Comment: @Sue, I agree, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @Sue No problem.